# ASP.NET Web API controller with attribute routing doesn't work without a route name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I use **attribute routing**, but when I specify an empty `Route` attribute I get the following error:

> 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

However, if I add a route name in the attribute, like `[Route("bar")]`, everything works as expected.

Why would one of these action methods work as expected, while the other one yields a **405** error?

```
[System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("foo")]
public partial class MyController : ApiController
{
   [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
   [System.Web.Http.Route("bar")] // I am able to POST to /foo/bar
   public async Task<MyResponseModel> BarMethod([FromBody]MyArgumentsModel arguments)
   {

   }

   [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
   [System.Web.Http.Route] // Error when I POST to /foo, "Method Not Allowed"
   public async Task<MyResponseModel> FooMethod([FromBody]MyArgumentsModel arguments)
   {

   }
}
```

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: You don't need to use [System.Web.Http.Route]. Just remove it and the method will inherit the controllers route.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include an empty string to the route attribute `[Route("")]` in order for it to work as the default route when using the route prefix.

The following article shows how it is done

Source: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes)

The result of the suggested change would look like this

```
[RoutePrefix("foo")]
public partial class MyController : ApiController {
   //eg POST foo/bar
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("bar")]
   public async Task<MyResponseModel> BarMethod([FromBody]MyArgumentsModel arguments) {
      //...
   }

   //eg POST foo    
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("")]
   public async Task<MyResponseModel> FooMethod([FromBody]MyArgumentsModel arguments) {
       //...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, adding an empty string yields the same result. :/

Comment: Check the examples in the article liked in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute routing can be combined with convention-based routing.
To define convention-based routes, call the MapHttpRoute method.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:"DefaultApi", 
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! Although I already have that exact configuration in place. :)

Comment: @TedNyberg Then try to rename `FooMethod` to `Post`

Comment: I tried that before, but it made no difference. :/ Thanks though!

Comment: @TedNyberg i have an application online that currently works with this configuration/ attributes...  what version of webapi/ framework are you using?

Comment: Version `5.2.3`. Weird thing is, this _has_ worked before. :/

Comment: @TedNyberg i use the same version :/